# Grouped and not grouped columns?

Tags: sql, group-by

Have this query:

```
SELECT brand, 
       ROUND(AVG(rating), 0) AS ar, 
       model
FROM engines
WHERE rating IS NOT NULL
AND rating != ''
AND category='Road'
GROUP BY brand
ORDER BY atr DESC
```

Problem is the model column.

How do I make the results show the model with the highest rating? (currently it just shows the first model that matches the filters).

i.e. if the data is:

```
brand1, model1, 3
brand1, model2, 5
brand1, model3, 4
```

How do I make the results be like:

```
brand1, 4, model2
```

(since model2 has the highest rating, 5)

Thanks!

Comment: Which `RDBMS` you are using.

Answer (score 1):

In `sql server` you can do this.

```
SELECT brand, 
       Round(Avg(rating), 0) AS ar, 
       Model = (SELECT TOP 1 E.model 
                FROM   engines E 
                ORDER  BY rating DESC) 
FROM   engines 
WHERE  rating IS NOT NULL 
       AND rating != '' 
       AND category = 'Road' 
GROUP  BY brand 
ORDER  BY atr DESC
```

In `mysql` change the sub-query to

```
SELECT E.model 
FROM   engines E 
ORDER  BY rating DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Using MySQL, but the query just returns 0s and 1s for the model column (I used your MySQL subquery in the main query as described)

Comment: @Louisa - What value is stored in `Model` column. Which column holds `model1,model2,..` values

Comment: The names of the models, i.e. "Model A", "Model B", etc.

Comment: @Louisa - Then you wont get `0s` and `1s` from that `sub-query`. I am selecting `E.model` column in sub-query

Comment: Yes, I was also quite surprised but I do get 0s and 1s. No idea why.

Answer (score 1):

The standard SQL would be:

```
select e.*
from (select e.*, row_number() over (partition by brand order by rating desc) as seqnum
      from engines e
     ) e
where seqnum = 1;
```

An alternative without window functions is:

```
select e.*
from engines e join
     (select brand, max(rating) as maxr
      from engines
      group by brand
     ) ee
     on e.brand = ee.brand and e.rating = ee.rating;
```